# Post session command - to send an email informaitca

Tags: informatica

i need to send an email using post session command,
 i used the below and it says it cant file the email  id , can  someone help me in figuring out where am i going wrong

uuencode $PMTargetFileDir/tgt_i914_carrier_amount_balancing.txt|$$EMAIL_IDS -m -s "Attached is the i914 report file generated while processing the ESI Weekly load" email@removed

Comment: What is Informatica server's operating system? Command uuencode may not work for all environment as expected.  you can use on-success mail command as well - i think that would be smoother.

Comment: What is `$$EMAIL_IDS`? What part of this command is supposed to be sending the email?